# How to get HTMLElement from child component in slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I get the Dom element of the child in slot. Attempts to get in the life hook onMounted () the el vnode property of an object is null

My-Component:

```html
<template>
   <div>{{text}}</div>
   <slot></slot>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "my-component",
    props: {
        text: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: true,
        },
    },
    setup( _, ctx) {
        
        onMounted( () => {
            if (ctx.slots.default) {
                console.log( (ctx.slots.default()[0]) ); // <- property "el" - is null
            }
        })

    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple things to keep in mind (for others looking to do the same)

- ✅ The slots object is passed in through the context which is the second parameter
- ✅ Unnamed slot content is accessed as default
- ✅ `slots.default` is a function that needs to be executed
- ✅ `slots.default()` returns an array, because a slot can have multiple elements, in most cases you can just pick `[0]`
- ❌ The content is only available **after** the component is rendered. In the example I used `onMounted`, which is probably the easiest.
- But, **if the passed element is a Vue component, the element is simply not available**

The slot is accessible through a function `slots.default()` that takes a data parameter that is used to render the slot. This can be useful for generating the nodes, if you want to use a render function, and seems to a large degree just some exposed internals.

I've found a couple hacks though to get around it using node traversal.

One (probably the better option) uses the child object (`slots.default()[0].children.default()[0].el.parentElement`)

And the other using a `ref` and a `nextElementSibling`.

The idea is that you put a span (or some other "invisible" element) that you can get a reference to using `ref`. Then in the `onMounted` handler, you can use that element to get to the slot element which is going to be the next element sibling.

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {return {}}
});

app.component("parent-component", {
  template: `<div><span ref="slotRef"></span><slot></slot></div>`,
  setup(props, ctx) {
    const slotRef = Vue.ref(null); // create a ref
    Vue.onMounted(()=>{
      const defaultSlot = ctx.slots.default();
      console.log(defaultSlot[0].children.default()[0].el.parentElement) // or get the parent of the first child
      defaultSlot[0].children.default()[0].el.parentElement.innerText += ""
      console.log(slotRef.value.nextElementSibling); // get the Sibling of ref
      slotRef.value.nextElementSibling.innerText += ""
    })
    return {slotRef};
  }
});
app.component("child-component", {
  template: `<div><slot></slot></div>`,
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```css
div{border:1px solid; padding:2px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent-component>
    <child-component>
      
    </child-component>
  </parent-component>
</div>
```

Comment: i need to get a parent element of children component 
`<my-component>
 <child-component/>
</my-component>`

Comment: just use the parent node of the slot element. Like this: `defaultSlot[0].el.parentNode`

Comment: i can't get parentNode if el is null... example https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hermann-1x4bp?file=/src/components/my-parent.vue

Comment: I gotcha now, my bad. Unfortunately if the element passed as a slot is a component, the $el is not available, but I've updated answer with some hacks to get to the element

Comment: also, check out this example that uses a render function and `withDirectives` https://jsfiddle.net/skirtle/rsnLda05/ for another option

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the solution in the jsfiddle example.